# Flutter: Store and retrieve formatted text in firestore/realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-packages

I am currently using [flutter_quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) pakage for formatting text. Now I want to store it in firestore /realtime database. I want to retrieve the formatted text as it is and show in my app.

After researching I came across [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) which will help me to display html code in my flutter app. This is great but now I also have to store html data to database.

So, how can I store html data to database using [flutter_quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) or [zefyrka](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyrka) or is there any text editor package which will help me to do my objective.

Any new suggestions are also welcomed. I just want to store and retrieve formatted text in firestore/realtime database using flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to encode your text in base64 and store the encoded text in cloud firestore. Please decode your encoded text before displaying it in your app.